# Center Align panel & MDI Child Form

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to center align a panel and MDI Child Forms inside an MDI parent container

Comment: What UI technology are you using?

Comment: i am working on windows forms with VC#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myPanel.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - myPanel.Width) / 2 ;
myPanel.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - myPanel.Height) / 2;
```

Is this similar to what you are looking for?

Comment: yes.. hey that's the technique i use to center DIVs in HTML\CSS